# SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

Tags: javascript, gulp, sass

gulpfile.jsで以下のようなエラーが出ます。
gulpは4.0です。

◆エラー

```
function browser-sync() {
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
```

どう書き直せば良いでしょうか？

◆gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

//pug
const pug = require('gulp-pug');
const fs = require('fs');
const data = require('gulp-data');
const path = require('path');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const notify = require('gulp-notify');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

//css
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const flexBugsFixes = require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'); //Sassにベンダープレフィックスをつける
const rename = require('gulp-rename'); //ファイルをリネーム

/**
 * 開発用のディレクトリを指定します。
 */
const src = {
  // 出力対象は`_`で始まっていない`.pug`ファイル。
  'html': ['src/**/*.pug', '!' + 'src/**/_*.pug'],
  // JSONファイルのディレクトリを変数化。
  'json': 'src/_data/',
  'css': 'src/**/*.css',
  'sass_style': ['src/**/*.scss', '!' + 'src/**/_*.scss'],
  //'styleguideWatch': 'src/**/*.scss',
  'js': 'src/**/*.js'
};

/**
 * 出力するディレクトリを指定します。
 */
const dest = {
  'root': 'dest/',
  'html': 'dest/'
};

/**
 * ローカルサーバーを起動します。
 */
function browser-sync() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: dest.root,
      index: "index.html"
    }
  });
}

/**
 * PugのコンパイルやCSSとjsの出力、browser-syncのリアルタイムプレビューを実行します。
 */
function watchFiles(done) {
  gulp.watch(src.html).on('change', gulp.series(html, browserReload));
  gulp.watch(src.scss).on('change', gulp.series(sass_style, browserReload));
  gulp.watch(src.css).on('change', gulp.series(css, browserReload));
  gulp.watch(src.js).on('change', gulp.series(js, browserReload));
}

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel(html, sass_style, css, js), gulp.series(browsersync, watchFiles)));

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

◆package.json

```
{
  "name": "gulp-pug-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GulpでPugを実行するためのテスト環境です。",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gulp",
    "pug"
  ],
  "author": "aaa",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-data": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-pug": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass-glob": "^1.0.9",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascriptの関数名に使える記号は、ドル記号($)とアンダースコア(_)だけです。
マイナス記号(-)は使えません。

ところが、質問のコードでは

```
function browser-sync()
```

とマイナス記号が使われているので"Unexpected token -"（使われていないはずの記号 - が見つかりました）とのエラーが出たのです。

＜修正案＞

```
function browser_sync() // マイナス記号の代わりにアンダースコアを使う
```

か

```
function browserSync() //　記号を使わないで、lower camel case(小文字で始めて、要素語の最初の文字だけを大文字にする書き方）にする
```

Comment: 質問したエラーは無くなりました。
ありがとうございます！